# Ionic app start working before initialization is finished

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an `Ionic` Barcode Scanner App with `Firebase` Realtime DB.
On the startup, the app should sync the data from `Firebase`. But somehow it seems like the app starts to work before the initialization / sync with the DB is completed. Hence the user will not see any data.

After a couple of restarts, the app finished to sync the data and the user can finally see the data.
Kindly guide me to fix this issue. That the app will sync the data every time the user uses the app?

Thanks in advance!

**tabs.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
import { DataServiceService } from '../../app/data-service.service';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast/ngx';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import * as moment from 'moment';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.page.scss'],
})
export class TabsPage implements OnInit {

  productViews: any = {};
  productViewsbyUser: any[] = [];
  isProdcutsAvailable = true;

  selectedProduct: any;
  isCameraOpen = false;
  showScan = false;
  products: any[] = [];
  productFound = true;
  displayUserName: any;

  exitModalDisplayed = false;


  constructor(
    private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,
    private toast: Toast,
    public platform: Platform,
    public dataService: DataServiceService,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    console.log(`Tabs Page called`);
    }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.productHunt();

  }

  productHunt() {
    this.dataService.getProducts()
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.products = <any[]><unknown>response;
      console.table('products ', this.products);
     });
  }

  getMoment() {
    return moment().milliseconds(0);
  }

// Start scanning procedure
  scan() {
    this.selectedProduct = {};
    this.isCameraOpen = true;
    this.showScan = true;
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isCameraOpen = false;
      }, 500);
      if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
        return;
      }
      console.log(`barcodeData`, barcodeData);
      this.selectedProduct = this.products.find(product => product.prodId === barcodeData.text);
      if (this.selectedProduct !== undefined) {
        this.selectedProduct.scannedAt = this.getMoment().toISOString();
        // this.selectedProduct.userName = this.displayUserName(); // TO TEST !!!
        this.productFound = true;
        // insert product views with firebase generated based key
        this.dataService.insertProductViewAnalytics(this.selectedProduct)
          .subscribe(() => {
            console.log(`Product view analytics inserted in Firebase`);
            this.initScanHistoryData();
          });
      } else {
        this.productFound = false;
        this.toast.show(`Product not found`, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
          toast => {
            console.log(toast);
          }
        );
      }
    }, (err) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isCameraOpen = false;
      }, 1000);
      this.toast.show(err, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
        toast => {
          console.log(toast);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  async initScanHistoryData() {
    this.dataService.getProductViewsForUser()
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.productViews = response;
        const userProductViews = [];
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (const key in this.productViews) {
          userProductViews.push(this.productViews[key]);
        }
          userProductViews.sort(function (a, b) {
            return moment(b.scannedAt).diff(moment(a.scannedAt));

            // ENTER USER NAME HERE???

        });

        this.productViewsbyUser = userProductViews;
        console.log('user productViews ', userProductViews);

        if (this.productViewsbyUser.length) {
          this.isProdcutsAvailable = true;
        } else {
          this.isProdcutsAvailable = false;
        }
        console.log('productViews ', this.productViews);
      });
  }
}
```

**data-service.service.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
import { DataServiceService } from '../../app/data-service.service';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast/ngx';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import * as moment from 'moment';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.page.scss'],
})
export class TabsPage implements OnInit {

  productViews: any = {};
  productViewsbyUser: any[] = [];
  isProdcutsAvailable = true;

  selectedProduct: any;
  isCameraOpen = false;
  showScan = false;
  products: any[] = [];
  productFound = true;
  displayUserName: any;

  exitModalDisplayed = false;


  constructor(
    private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,
    private toast: Toast,
    public platform: Platform,
    public dataService: DataServiceService,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    console.log(`Tabs Page called`);
    }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.productHunt();

  }

  productHunt() {
    this.dataService.getProducts()
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.products = <any[]><unknown>response;
      console.table('products ', this.products);
     });
  }

  getMoment() {
    return moment().milliseconds(0);
  }

// Start scanning procedure
  scan() {
    this.selectedProduct = {};
    this.isCameraOpen = true;
    this.showScan = true;
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isCameraOpen = false;
      }, 500);
      if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
        return;
      }
      console.log(`barcodeData`, barcodeData);
      this.selectedProduct = this.products.find(product => product.prodId === barcodeData.text);
      if (this.selectedProduct !== undefined) {
        this.selectedProduct.scannedAt = this.getMoment().toISOString();
        // this.selectedProduct.userName = this.displayUserName(); // TO TEST !!!
        this.productFound = true;
        // insert product views with firebase generated based key
        this.dataService.insertProductViewAnalytics(this.selectedProduct)
          .subscribe(() => {
            console.log(`Product view analytics inserted in Firebase`);
            this.initScanHistoryData();
          });
      } else {
        this.productFound = false;
        this.toast.show(`Product not found`, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
          toast => {
            console.log(toast);
          }
        );
      }
    }, (err) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isCameraOpen = false;
      }, 1000);
      this.toast.show(err, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
        toast => {
          console.log(toast);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  async initScanHistoryData() {
    this.dataService.getProductViewsForUser()
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.productViews = response;
        const userProductViews = [];
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (const key in this.productViews) {
          userProductViews.push(this.productViews[key]);
        }
          userProductViews.sort(function (a, b) {
            return moment(b.scannedAt).diff(moment(a.scannedAt));

            // ENTER USER NAME HERE???

        });

        this.productViewsbyUser = userProductViews;
        console.log('user productViews ', userProductViews);

        if (this.productViewsbyUser.length) {
          this.isProdcutsAvailable = true;
        } else {
          this.isProdcutsAvailable = false;
        }
        console.log('productViews ', this.productViews);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: As a UI note you want SOMETHING to show on the screen even if it isn't the data because that is still being fetched, a spinner, progress bar, etc. And the tab is loading and then calling for the data so there will always be that delay. If you just show a blank screen for several seconds studies show users will ditch your app very quickly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment. I got your point. But the problem is, that the app will start running and some data was not fetched yet and it also will not be synced afterwards unfortunately. Only after several restarts of the app, the whole data got loaded.

Comment: Is the tabs page the start page? You could move the call to the service into the app.component so it begins even earlier. The fetching of the data is going to affected by random factors so you can never assume it will always load at a certain rate. The syncing afterwards sounds a different (and more important) issue.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks again for you answer. I tried to call the service in the app.componet file but unfortunately it didn't work. After login it seems like somehow the pruduct data was not synced. Same with other data such as profile data etc.

Comment: You can use angular lifecycle events and ionic page lifecycle events such as `ngAfterViewInits` and `ionViewDidEnter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used this solution to fix the issue: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-reload-page-every-time-click-on-tabs/115947/4

Thanks a lot for your help guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you pasted your Tabs component twice instead of your data service, but if your goal is to make it wait then it looks to me like you're just not adding awaits on your async functions, for example:

```
async initScanHistoryData() {
    await this.dataService.getProductViewsForUser()
    ...
}
```

That being said, as mentioned in some of the comments, this is probably not the best of practices and to give a better user experience, you should allow your asynchronous function to work "synchronously", have the page load, and show the user a spinner or some feedback to show that the database is still fetching until the data comes back from the database.